# Web3.js function 'sign' - where does it obtain the private key from?

Tags: web3js, private-key

I'm reading Web3.js docs on function `web3.eth.sign` ([here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sign)), which state:

> The address parameter can also be an address or index from the `web3.eth.accounts.wallet`. It will then sign locally using the private key of this account.

But how exactly does it obtain the private key of the given account?

Thank you!

Comment: for this one, you need to unlock the account. I guess this is coming from the previous question that you already solved.

Comment: @Jaime: Yep, it does. But I want to avoid account-unlocking.